# Parâmetro this fora do esperado dentro de uma função anônima

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, contexto

Fiz um código para treinar manipulação de Arrays e JavaScript. Eis parte do código:

```js
function Playlist (nome ='Playlist'){
    const musicas = [];
    function addMusicas(...novasMusicas){
        novasMusicas.forEach(function(musica){
            // aqui o this é o objeto global
            this.musicas.unshift(musica);
        })
    }
    return {
        nome,
        musicas,
        addMusicas,
    }
}

const playlist01 = new Playlist(); 
playlist01.addMusicas('Dream on', 'Drive', 'Sex and Candy');
```

Percebam que quem executa a função dentro do `forEach` é o objeto global. Sem o `this`, o escopo é o do objeto criado por `Playlist()`. Alguém pode me explicar por que isso ocorre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois quando uma função não é uma propriedade de um objeto, ela é invocada com o paramêtro `this` ligada ao objeto global.

Existem varias formas de escapar disso, poderia utilizar [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call), [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript). Mas pelo fato da pergunta ter a tag ES6, recomendo que use uma [arrow function](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/), pois ela conserva o `this` de onde ela foi criada.

Veja como ficaria:

```js
function Playlist (nome ='Playlist'){
    const musicas = [];
    function addMusicas(...novasMusicas){
        novasMusicas.forEach(musica => { // perceba aqui a sintaxe da criação de uma arrow function
            this.musicas.unshift(musica);
        })
    }
    return {
        nome,
        musicas,
        addMusicas,
    }
}

const playlist01 = new Playlist(); 
playlist01.addMusicas('Dream on', 'Drive', 'Sex and Candy');
console.log(playlist01.musicas);
```

Comment: Só não entendi a funcionalidade da variável **nome** no código.

Comment: Copiei da pergunta, também não entendi kk. De qualquer forma preferi deixar...

Comment: KKKK... blza Francisco.

Comment: @LeAndrade, eu só copiei parte do código e esqueci de apagar o que não tava usando. O foco mesmo é na pergunta rsrs.

Comment: @Francisco, todas as funções anônimas têm esse comportamento?

Comment: Cara, o fato não é ser uma função anonima, isso não muda o this. O `this` muda dependendo de como a função é chamada.

Comment: @Francisco Mas nesse caso, como o objeto global pode acessar a função que tá dentro do forEach, se ele está executando dentro da função addMusicas? Tem algum método pra entender de forma mais clara o contexto de execução em JavaScript?

Comment: O objeto global não acessa a função, a função acessa o objeto global. Sobre recomendação, eu não tenho, mas é só dar uma googlada que você acha muitos [artigos e docs legais](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Achei esse aqui no Medium https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0